# Meaning of significance test

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I was wondering what relation and differences are between a significance test and a hypothesis test? Are they the same concept, or is the former a special case of the latter, or ...?

What does a significance test mean?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: they are the same

Comment: See the answers to a similar question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16218/what-is-the-difference-between-testing-of-hypothesis-and-test-of-significance