# High p value - Low Effect size

Tags: p-value, effect-size

What does it mean to have a high p value but a very very low effect size? What can I conclude? Is it necessary to report the effect size when p=0.998?

Comment: Have you constructed a confidence interval for the effect size? That may be helpful.

Comment: Why the "but" between "high p value" and "very very low effect size"?? Wouldn't a high p-value be expected to go with a low effect size? There's no hint of a contradiction that would suggest "but".

Comment: A high $p$-value is telling you the observations are close to those predicted by the null hypothesis, while a low $p$-value would suggest that the observations  appear more extreme under that hypothesis.  Seeing $99999$ heads when flipping a possibly biased coin $200000$ times ($p=0.9982$) does not guarantee the coin is unbiased, but does suggest that the extent of any bias is likely to be very small.

Comment: This page asks (and answers) essentially the same question:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330713/justification-for-reporting-non-significant-effect-sizes/627783#627783

Answer (score 5):

There is a strong case for reporting effect sizes alongside p-values, as they both represent two different things. The p-value indicates certainty/uncertainty, whereas the effect size tells you about the magnitude of the effect. You can read this article for example:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3444174/

And refer to this post:

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Do-I-need-to-report-effect-size-when-p-value-shows-not-significant-result

You could report both the effect size and p-value, saying that the difference between the two levels of your variable is small and non significant for example.